# How to split an allocation region so that the two regions can be reallocated separately?

Tags: memory-management, rust, systems-programming

I want to split an allocated memory region in two at a specific point, so that those two regions can be `realloc`'d separately. I want to do this because I want to free space in the middle of the region.

My idea is to do something like this:

```
┌───────────────────────────────┐
│ Allocated                     │
└───────────────────────────────┘
              ↓
          split( );
              ↓
┌───────────────┬───────────────┐
│ Allocated     │ Allocated     │
└───────────────┴───────────────┘
              ↓
         realloc( );
              ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────────┐
│ Allocated │   │ Allocated     │
└───────────┘   └───────────────┘
```

Is this possible in Rust? If so, how?

Comment: nor it can be done in rust

Comment: _"I want to do this because I want to free space in the middle of the region."_ This is definitely an XY problem. You may just have to redesign the data structure around the problem.

Comment: @E_net4likesmanythings I didn't want to give many details, but the data structure I want to implement is a kind of linked list. I want O(1) removal, so when I remove a node in the middle, I don't want to move the other nodes around. I guess I'll have to manually keep track of the free parts inside the allocated regions, since it's not possible to make the allocator do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (currently) not possible.

Rust's memory allocation API is in [the `alloc` module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/alloc/alloc/index.html). And as you can see, the functionality you need is not offered there.

In theory, allocators could offer such a feature. However, in practice, this is usually not offered nor used. The standard allocation API in C also does not offer this as far as I know.